# Shift bulk rows in a matrix by a shifting index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Note that I'm using Matlab R2013b. So, I have a toy input matrix of 10x2 size:

```
inputM = [NaN 4 7 NaN 9 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN; NaN NaN 8 10 2 NaN 3 NaN NaN NaN]
```

I have the lowest and highest positions where the non-NaN values are located in each column:

```
lowest_idx = [2 3]
highest_idx = [5 7]
```

I want to shift the bulk rows, between the lowest and highest positions, downward according to a shifting index `shift_idx = [3 2]`. The output matrix I need to obtain looks like

```
outputM = [NaN NaN NaN NaN 4 7 NaN 9 NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN NaN 8 10 2 NaN 3 NaN]
```

I can do this using a `for loop` like this:

```
for i = 1:length(shift_idx)
    inputM(lowest_idx(i)+shift_idx(i):highest_idx(i)+shift_idx)(i),i) = inputM(lowest_idx(i):highest_idx(i),i);
    inputM(1:lowest_idx(i)+1,i) = nan;
end
```

However, my real matrix has over 1 million columns, so I'd like a more efficient solution. Anyone has an idea of how to do this without a `for loop`?

Answer (score 0):

[`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) does exactly this.

```
outputM  = circshift(inputM.', shift_idx).';
```

Comment: @Sadar Usama I tried your solution, but the columns in `outputM` are interchanged, which I don't want. I only want a shift with rows, not with columns, since I'm treating the rows separately. The only way I managed to do this using `circshift` is still using a `for loop` like `for i = 1:numel(n)
outputM(:,i) = circshift(inputM(:,i), shift_idx(i));
end`

Comment: @Bowecho your code gives this output: `[NaN 4; NaN NaN]` are you sure that you want this? My code gives the output that you wrote in your original question

Answer (score 0):

If you can access Matlab R2016a, use [circshift](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html). For example,

```
outputM = circshift(inputM, shift_idx);
```

If you don't have modern version of `circshift`, you will need to use the old version twice. Once along each dimension. For example,

```
for i = 1:numel(size(shift_idx))
  outputM = circshift(inputM, shift_idx(i),i);
end
```

WARNING: the above is not intended to accomplish exactly what you asked. But give it a try. You will see what it does.

In your particular problem, since you are treating each row differently, the shift is going to be more computationally demanding. You can nevertheless use `circshift`. For example,

```
outputM = [circshift(inputM(:,1), shift_idx(1),2); circshift(inputM(:,1), shift_idx(2),2)];
```

Make sure you read the documentation and do testing on simple examples first though. You also need to know the behaviors of how the unfilled elements are moved.